# Ramda function that evaluates equality of functions when applied to an argument

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm looking for a function that takes two functions and returns a function that when applied to an argument, returns true or false if those functions return the same value when applied to the given argument.

You can accomplish this like so:

```
R.converge(R.equals, [func1, func2])
```

A silly example:

```
const eq = R.converge(R.equals, [R.T, R.identity]);

eq('foo') // false
eq(true) // true
```

I'm looking for a more elegant way to accomplish this though.

Comment: That seems really fine. What don't you like about it?

Comment: How do you define "more elegant"? This question seems pretty opinion-based.

Comment: @4castle I suppose so. I'm a bit surprised Ramda doesn't offer this out of the box though.

Comment: `R.bothEqual = (f1, f2) => R.converge(R.equals, [f1, f2]);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one possibility:

```
const eq = lift(R.equals);
eq(R.T, R.identity)('foo'); //=> false
eq(R.T, R.identity)(true); //=> true
```

You might or might not find this more elegant.  Obviously you could name `eq(T, identity)` to get a reusable function.

> I'm a bit surprised Ramda doesn't offer this out of the box though

I wonder why.  I've never had a requirement for such a thing.  It's never been raised as an [issue](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues) on the Ramda repository.  What's your use-case?